# Render raw HTML in Preact without using Preact Markup?

Tags: javascript, preact

Preact Markup is 8.5kb, which is half the size of Preact. Is there a way to render raw HTML without having to parse it?

One way I can think of is to render a placeholder and then replace the placeholder in `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` using `innerHTML`, but is there a less hacky way?

Comment: preact-X has `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`.

Answer (score 16):

As @pmkro mentioned in a comment, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render raw html strings.

```js
import { h, render } from "preact";

const vnode = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: "<span>foobar</span>"
}} />

render(vnode, document.getElementById("app"));
// renders <div><span>foobar</span></div>
```

A fair bit of warning: You need to make absolutely sure the string that ends up in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is properly escaped. Otherwise you open yourself (and your users) up to XSS injection attacks. Hence the name `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Disclaimer: I work on Preact.

Comment: Are attacks like this a concern for data coming from trusted sources as well?
What exactly has to be escaped?

Answer (score 0):

If size is the issue, then why not use https://github.com/developit/htm ? In the repo it says that the size is less than 500 bytes if used with preact.

Comment: `htm` is not raw HTML. Instead its a way to author in a JSX-like format without the need for transpilation. It's light, but not free, nor does it get around the parsing issue mentioned.